# Using variables from two views inside an Angular module

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a variable, which I got from a querystring in docA:

**docA(mainView)**

```
var cat = getUrlParameter('cat');
```

I also have an ng-click function in docB that handles different views:

**docB(rightDrawer)**

```
<li class="item" ng-click="newDay('Monday')">Monday</li>
```

**$scope.newDay**

```
$scope.newDay= function(day){
    supersonic.ui.layers.push('http://localhost/principal.html?day='+day +'&cat='+cat);
    supersonic.ui.drawers.close('right');
}
```

I'm trying to pass de var "cat" from docA to $scope.newDay

I tried:

calling $window.cat inside $scope.newDay, but got undefined, I assume it is because I'm trying to get a variable from docA inside a function in docB.

**GOAL:**

go to:

> http://localhost/principal.html?day=Lunes&cat=0

from the "scope.newDay" function using variable "cat" from docA and "day" from [docB]newDay('Monday')

Comment: what is this supersonic?

Comment: It's a framework that helps me build mobile applications. In the code I posted it pushes a view to the main View and closes a sidemenu

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you look into directives. Agular isolates scopes. With directives you can inherrit scope.